# Cost to get missing Entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My app can calculate a small number Keys for which Entities often do not exist in the datastore.  For example, I may send a bulk get for 15 keys, of which only 4 return entities.

Docs simply state that a get is charged as one Read operation.  Is this still true when the Entity does not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You will pay for key allocation (per key), and will be changed the small fees (currently it cost $0.01 per 100k operations).</strike>

If I understand the [billing page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing) getting 10 entities using keys will cost you 10 small units + read units * entities found.

---

I decided to check that myself, **tl;dr** you are not going to like the results.

I created a simple model, and a handler that request the model 10,000 times.

```
class DevNull(db.Model):
    pass

class EmptyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
    def get(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            keys = [db.Key.from_path('DevNull', i*j+1) for j in xrange(1000)]
            res = DevNull.get(keys)

            print len(res)
```

The read quota spike each time by 10,000 read operation, 5 of those would kill the free quota.

Comment: I am not allocating keys which is only needed when you want GAE to create a unique id for you.  My app can calculate which keys it needs to look up but they may not exist.  The doc you link to states that each GET (using a key) costs only one read unit (no small units). To clarify, I do not know if I am charged for missing Entities as well as the returned Entities

Comment: "The read quota spike each time by 10,000 read operation, 5 of those would kill the free quota." - yes, 5 times 10,000 is 50,000.

Comment: Wow! Yes sad news indeed.  Great test! Can't upvote you yet sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"No, you are only charged for entities that exist and are returned."

*I have my fingers crossed that this will be the official response from Google. :D*

Comment: Alas. :-) Looking up a non-existent key takes almost as much effort as looking up an existing key. By the time we find out there's no entity we've already done the heavy lifting.

Comment: I see. But this is not the same with queries, right? query.fetch(100) that returns only 50 entity is charged only for that 50 + 1, right?

Comment: Yes, the fetch limit doesn't enter into the cost -- only the actual work that is done to satisfy the query.  I'm not sure what you'll be charged if the fetch() returns 0 entities, it should still cost something, probably depending on how many indexes were consulted.  Also note that if you specify an offset, fetch() may return 0 results but you will be charged for the items skipped to satisfy the offset.  I should probably shut up because I don't know all the details here.

Comment: The details are here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs . Basically a query costs 1 read + 1 per returned entity; a Get costs one read per key requested.